# How do you return a pointer from a function outside of main()

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

My question is aboutt dynamic memory allocation in C. I have been asked to dynamically allocate an array of `n` longs, and return the pointer to the first element of this array. I have some code to test the output of this but the memory allocation is failing.

```
long* make_long_array(long n)
{
    int i;
    int *a;

    a = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
    if (a == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR: Out of memory\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; *(a + i++) = 0);
    return *a;
}
```

Im getting an error on two lines saying

> 'error: return makes pointer from integer without cast'

this occurs for the lines

```
return 1;
```

and

```
return *a;
```

I'm not entirely sure how to fix this. I think the error in `return 1;` being that I am trying to return an integer when it is looking for a pointer? But I am not sure how to fix it for the return of the pointer. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the meaning of returning 1 when you have no memory. Return nullptr instead. Also you want to return a long* and you are returning an int. Also the for loop is wrong. Generally, you need to study more.

Comment: `return a;` should work. By the way, if you need to set all elements to 0, use `calloc()`. And `a` should be `long*`.

Comment: long* make_long_array(long n) means a function declaration that accepts one argument of type long and the result that it returns is of type pointer to an address of type long. When you say return 1 you are in trouble, especially if you try to dereference the value stored at address 1. You can use calloc function instead, so no need to call the for loop.

Comment: so I understand I was trying to return an integer when casting a long which has now been fixed. @Michael, I am not sure what you mean that the for loop is wrong, I have tested it and it seems to work. also the use of nullptr throws up another error of unassigned variable, do I need to include another library for this?

Comment: nullptr is `NULL` in C.

Comment: *I am not sure what you mean that the for loop is wrong,* – The loop is not wrong but unnecessary if you'd use the correct function to allocate the memory: `calloc()`. (which initializes the memory allocated with 0)

Comment: *[...] the for loop [...]* – Could be written like `for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) a[i] = 0;` which is much easier to read. But as said before: Use `calloc()` or, if you insist using `malloc()` use `memset()` to set the memory to zero.

Answer (score 4):

To fix your original version:

```
long* make_long_array(/* long not the correct type for sizes of objects */ size_t n)
{
    // int i;  define variables where they're used.
    /* int you want to return a */ long *a; // array.

    a = /* (int*) no need to cast */ malloc(sizeof(/* int */ you want */ long /*s, remember? *) */ ) * n);
    if (a == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR: Out of memory\n");  // puts()/fputs() would be sufficient.
        return /* 1 */ NULL;  // 1 is an integer. Also it is uncommon to return
    }                         // anything other than NULL when a memory allocation
                              // fails.

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; /* *(a + i++) = 0 that falls into the category obfuscation */ ++i )
        /* more readable: */ a[i] = 0;
    // return *a; you don't want to return the first long in the memory allocated
    return a; // but the address you got from malloc()
}
```

A *Better Way*<sup>*tm*</sup> to write such allocations is

```
FOO_TYPE *foo = malloc(NUM_ELEMENTS * sizeof(*foo)); // or
BAR_TYPE *bar = calloc(NUM_ELEMENTS, sizeof(*bar));
```

By using `*foo` and `*bar` as the operand of `sizeof` you don't have to worry about changing it when the type of `foo` or `bar` changes.

Your function can be simplified to

```
#include <stddef.h>  // size_t
#include <stdlib.h>  // calloc()

long* make_long_array(size_t size)      // size_t is guaranteed to be big enough to hold
{                                       // all sizes of objects in memory and indexes
    return calloc(size, sizeof(long));  // into them. calloc() initializes the memory
}                                       // it allocates with zero.

// if you really want an error-message printed:

long* make_long_array(size_t size)
{
    long *data = calloc(size, sizeof(long));
    if (!data)  // calloc() returned NULL
        fputs("Out of memory :(\n\n", stderr);  // Error messages should go to stderr
    return data;                                // since it is unbuffered*) and
}                                               // might be redirected by the user.
```

*) so the user gets the message instantly.

Also there is no need to cast the result of `*alloc()` since they return a `void*` which is implicitly convertible in every other pointer type.

Could be written as a macro so it not only works for `long` but for any type:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAKE_ARRAY(TYPE, COUNT) calloc((COUNT), sizeof((TYPE)))

// sample usage:

int main(void)
{
    int  *foo = MAKE_ARRAY(*foo, 12);
    long *bar = MAKE_ARRAY(*bar, 24);
    char *qux = MAKE_ARRAY(*qux, 8);

    free(qux);
    free(bar);
    free(foo);
}
```